# Implicit cast to a base class - Resharper shows error

Tags: c#, resharper

I am wondering why Resharper 2017.1.2 shows an error "Conversion to base class", but the code does compile. Is this a bad practice to do the kind of implicit cast as shown below?

```
/// <summary>
/// A generic range class.
/// </summary>
class Range<TBar>
{
    public TBar From { get; }
    public TBar To { get; }

    public Range(TBar rangeFrom, TBar rangeTo)
    {
        From = rangeFrom;
        To = rangeTo;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// A specific range class.
/// </summary>
class DateTimeRange : Range<DateTime>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Conversion to Range of DateTimeOffset...
    /// Here Resharper shows an error.
    /// </summary>
    public static implicit operator Range<DateTimeOffset>(DateTimeRange range)
    {
        return new Range<DateTimeOffset>(range.From, range.To);
    }

    public DateTimeRange(DateTime rangeFrom, DateTime rangeTo) : base(rangeFrom, rangeTo)
    {
    }

    // Some DateTime specific methods...
}
```

The idea behind this contraption is to be able to do the following cast:

```
var foo = new DateTimeRange(DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MaxValue);
var baz = (Range<DateTimeOffset>) foo;
```

Comment: When `DateTimeRange` inherits from `Range<DateTimeOffset>` a cast to it is pointless and adds no functionality. Why do you want this?

Comment: @HimBromBeere: No, `DateTimeRange` derives from `Range<DateTime>`, not `Range<DateTimeOffset>`.